# In a Wicket 6.x RadioGroup how do I setEscapeModelString(false) on choices?

Tags: radio-button, escaping, wicket-6

I need each choice to have a label on two lines with a line break at a specific point in the String.  I have put <br/> where I want the break but it is being escaped.  How can I stop the value of the name field on my model from being escaped? The following code does not give me the result I want:

```
...
final RadioGroup<WebShippingMethodDO> rg =
  initShipMethodOptionView(view, methodsModel, shipModel, shipMethodId, methods);
shipMethodForm.add(rg.setEscapeModelStrings(false));
...
```

The result is as follows:

```
...
<label for="shipMethodBtnac">FEDEX INTL ECONOMY&lt;br/&gt;(3 - 5 Days)</label>
...
```

But this is what I want:

```
...
<label for="shipMethodBtnac">FEDEX INTL ECONOMY<br/>(3 - 5 Days)</label>
...
```

How do I turn off the escaping?

Answer (score 0):

```
...
final RadioGroup<WebShippingMethodDO> rg =
  initShipMethodOptionView(view, methodsModel, shipModel, shipMethodId, methods);

// turn off escaping on rg's children
rg.visitChildren(new IVisitor<Component,Object>(){      
  @Override
  public void component(Component child, IVisit<Object> visit)
  {
    child.setEscapeModelStrings(false);
  }      
});

shipMethodForm.add(rg);
...
```